# JavaFX button action not accessing the ListView selected item

Tags: java, listview, button, javafx, event-handling

My partner and I are having an issue with our button click's `ActionEvent`. Its not calculating the price of the individual items.

> Instructions:
>
> Include an event handler method for the `Button` that calculates the
>   “total bill” as follows: the “price” field from the `ObservableList`
>   that matches the selected “item” from the `ListView` (the user may
>   purchase only one item at a time) times sales tax (8.625%) plus the
>   tip which is the matching “price” from the `ObservableList` times the
>   percentage from the `Slider`; display with text labels in the “result”
>   `Label` the selected “item”, its matching “price”, the sales tax, the
>   amount of the “tip” and the “total bill”

The Code:

```
public class TipCalculator extends Application
{
    private DecimalFormat twoDecimals;
    //private float percentage;

    private Label lblHeader;
    private Label lblResults;
    private Label lblTip;

    private ObservableList<String> item;
    private ObservableList<Double> price;

    private Slider sliderTipPercent;

    private FlowPane flowTipPercent;

    private ListView listView;

    private VBox vBoxSliders;
    private VBox vBoxListView;
    private VBox vBoxResults;

    private Button btnCalculate;
    //NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        // Instantiates a DecimalFormat object to format the Labels linked to the Sliders  
        twoDecimals = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        // Make the heading Label and format
        lblHeader = new Label("McDonald's Order");
        lblHeader.setMinWidth(800);
        lblHeader.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        lblHeader.setStyle("-fx-font-family: 'Impact'; -fx-font-size: 28px; -fx-text-fill: yellow; -fx-background-color: rgb(212, 31, 6); -fx-font-weight: bold;");

        // Instantiate 10 Orders      
        Order order1 = new Order("Big Mac", 9.75);
        Order order2 = new Order("Chicken Nuggets", 3.25);
        Order order3 = new Order("Quarter Pounder", 8.25);
        Order order4 = new Order("Double Quarter Pounder", 9.75);
        Order order5 = new Order("Filet O'Fish", 8.25);
        Order order6 = new Order("Bacon Clubhouse", 9.75);
        Order order7 = new Order("McGriddle", 4.25);
        Order order8 = new Order("McDouble", 2.25);
        Order order9 = new Order("McChicken", 2.25);
        Order order10 = new Order("Cheeseburger", 2.25);

        // Instantiate and format the "hours worked" Slider and the elements linked to it
        // The "hours worked" Slider and Label are placed side by side in a FlowPane      
        lblTip = new Label("Tip Percent");

        sliderTipPercent = new Slider(0.0, 25.0, 15.0);
        sliderTipPercent.setShowTickMarks(true);
        sliderTipPercent.setShowTickLabels(true);
        sliderTipPercent.setMajorTickUnit(5.0);
        sliderTipPercent.setMinorTickCount(4);
        sliderTipPercent.setPrefWidth(300);
        sliderTipPercent.setOnMouseDragged( e -> updateTipPercentSlider(e) );

        lblTip = new Label( twoDecimals.format( sliderTipPercent.getValue() ) );

        flowTipPercent = new FlowPane(sliderTipPercent, lblTip);
        flowTipPercent.setHgap(10);           

        // Place the Sliders and related elements into the "sliders" VBox

        vBoxSliders = new VBox(7, flowTipPercent);
        vBoxSliders.setMinWidth(500);
        vBoxSliders.setPadding( new Insets(10) );

        // Instantiate the "results" Label and "calculate" Button
        // Place those elements into the "results" VBox and format
        lblResults = new Label("Result:");
        lblResults.setStyle("-fx-font-family: 'Arial'; -fx-font-size: 25px; -fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-text-fill: black;");

        btnCalculate = new Button("Calculate Total Bill");
        btnCalculate.setPadding( new Insets(10) );
        btnCalculate.setMaxWidth(150);
        btnCalculate.setStyle("-fx-font-family: 'Impact'; -fx-background-color: rgb(212, 31, 6); -fx-font-size: 15px; -fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-text-fill: yellow;");
        btnCalculate.setOnAction( e -> handleClickAction(e) );

        vBoxResults = new VBox(35, lblTip, btnCalculate, lblResults);
        btnCalculate.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        vBoxResults.setPadding( new Insets(15) );
        vBoxResults.setPrefWidth(175);
        vBoxResults.setPrefHeight(100);
        vBoxResults.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white; -fx-border-color: black; -fx-border-radius: 20;");

        // Instantiate on ObservableList of titles from the Book class
        // Instantiate an ObservableList of Book objects

        item = FXCollections.observableArrayList (order1.getItem(), order2.getItem(),
                order3.getItem(), order4.getItem(), order5.getItem(), order6.getItem(),
                order7.getItem(), order8.getItem(), order9.getItem(), order10.getItem());

        price = FXCollections.observableArrayList(order1.getPrice(), order2.getPrice(),
                order3.getPrice(), order4.getPrice(), order5.getPrice(), order6.getPrice(),
                order7.getPrice(), order8.getPrice(), order9.getPrice(), order10.getPrice());

        // Create a ListView from the "book title" ObservableList
        // Place the ListView into the "ListView" VBox
        listView = new ListView(item);
        listView.setOnMouseClicked( e -> updateSelectedOrder(e) );

        vBoxListView = new VBox(listView);
        vBoxListView.setPadding( new Insets(10) );
        vBoxListView.setPrefWidth(200);
        vBoxListView.setPrefHeight(200);

        // Instantiate the GridPane
        // Insert the "heading" Label into the first row
        // Insert the "ListView" and "result" VBoxes into the second row
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();  

        //LabelHeader
        grid.addRow(0, lblHeader);
        GridPane.setColumnSpan(lblHeader, 4);
        GridPane.setHalignment(lblHeader, HPos.CENTER);

        //Results & Button
        grid.addRow(1, vBoxListView, sliderTipPercent, lblTip );

        //List
        grid.addRow(2, vBoxResults, btnCalculate);
        GridPane.setColumnSpan(vBoxResults, 4);
        GridPane.setHalignment(btnCalculate, HPos.RIGHT);

        // Instantiate the Scene, set the properties for the Stage and set the Scene into it
        // Show the PrimaryStage
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 515, 300);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Tip Calculator");
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * Updates the Label for hours worked when a MouseDragged event occurs for
     * the "hours worked" Slider.
     *
     * @param event the MouseEvent parameter
     */
    private void updateTipPercentSlider(MouseEvent e)
    {
        lblTip.setText( twoDecimals.format( sliderTipPercent.getValue() ) );
    }

   private void handleClickAction(ActionEvent e)
    {

        double tip = sliderTipPercent.getValue();
        double priceItem = price.get(0);
        double totalBill = 0;

        if (tip > 0)
        {
          totalBill = priceItem * (8.625 / 100) + priceItem * (tip / 100);
        }

        lblResults.setText( String.format("Total Bill: $%.2f", totalBill) );
    }

    /**
     * Gets the index from the Book "author" ListView control and uses it to
     * access a matching element from the "book" ObservableList and displays
     * that element in the "results" Label.
     *
     * @param event the MouseEvent parameter
     */
    private void updateSelectedOrder(MouseEvent e)
    {
        int index = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        lblResults.setText( item.get(index) );
        lblResults.setText( price.get(index).toString());
    }    

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: *It's not calculating* means...? The label doesn't change at all? The label shows wrong or $0 bill? There is an exception?

Comment: The result label keeps showing TotalBill $2.30 no matter what item i choose. If I choose Big Mack it will display the price 9.75. But, when I click "Calculate Total Bill" it keeps displaying $2.30.

Comment: Firstly, you used `price.get(0)`. Secondly, your bill is weird because it does not include the original price into it. How the value ended up this way, you probably have to step into your codes to find out.

Comment: You can try this code: (1) Define an instance variable `private int selectedIndex;` (2) In the `updateSelectedOrder` method add this line: `selectedIndex = index;` (3) In the `handleClickAction` change the code to: `double priceItem = price.get(selectedIndex);`

Comment: You seem to correctly access the elements in `updateSelectedOrder` (even though this for some reason seems to refer to books). I recommend creating an `Product` type though and using a single `ObservableList<Product>`/`ListView<Product>` with a custom `cellFactory` making access to the selected data much simpler. Also note that there is a logical issue with the instructions: taxes get added on top of the regular price (multiplication by (100+8.625)%). The instructions tell you to simply calculate the sum of the taxes and the tip.